# Dar Formato PHP en Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, formato, vscode

Actualmente tengo varios archivos php que esta desordenada, me refiero que esta algo asi:

```
<thead>
            <tr style="background:#339999;color:white;">
              <th>ID</th>
                <th>APELLIDO PATERNO</th>
              <th>APELLIDO MATERNO</th>
                <th>NOMBRES</th>
            <th>DNI</th>
            <th>CARGO</th>     
            <th>RAZON SOCIAL</th>
                <th></th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
```

y quisiera corregirlo a la siguiente manera:

```
         <thead>
          <tr style="background:#339999;color:white;">
            <th>ID</th>
              <th>APELLIDO PATERNO</th>
              <th>APELLIDO MATERNO</th>
              <th>NOMBRES</th>
              <th>DNI</th>
              <th>CARGO</th>     
              <th>RAZON SOCIAL</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
```

me podrian compartir algun plugin o herramienta para poder ordenar mi codigo.

Comment: Puedes cambiar la etiqueta de PHP por la de html?

Comment: Las preguntas pidiendo recomendaciones de software, libros, plugins, etc. se consideran basadas en opiniones y no se ajustan bien al contenido del sitio. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Debes instalar el plugin Prettier - Code formatter para html css javascript no obstante no tiene soporte para PHP, pero en el codigo html funciona perfectamente.

Existe una extención de nombre PHP Formatter pero no he podido ponerla a correr correctamente en mi VSCode.

Saludos...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ordenarlas manualmente con Ctrl+alt y seleccionando cada uno esto hace que tengas multi cursores, luego das A la tecla TAB cuantas veces quieras. Esto si quieres ordenarlo manualmente! Suerte!

Answer (score -1):

acá te dejo unas extensiones para formatear codigo php en VS Code:

- Para un archivo que contenga html y php usa esta extensión [Format HTML in PHP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rifi2k.format-html-in-php)
- Para un archivo con puro código php usa esta extensión [phpfmt - PHP formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt)

Answer (score -2):

El formateo de código está disponible en VS Code a través de estos atajos de teclado:

- En Windows <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- En Mac <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- En Ubuntu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Alternativamente, puedes encontrar el atajo, así como otros, a través de la funcionalidad de búsqueda del editor, que se abre con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd> (o <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> en Mac), y luego buscando ***format document***.

<sub>Traducido de la respuesta en Stack Overflow [How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973358/1983854)</sub>

Comment: Puedes identar el codigo o darle formato seleccionandolo y presionando la combinacion de teclas segun tu SO  

En Windows Shift + Alt + F, En Mac Mayús + Opción + F, En Ubuntu Ctrl + Shift + I

Comment: @DavidGarcia Por favor edita la respuesta para colocar la traducción ahí. Los comentarios son principalmente para cuestiones temporales.

Comment: muchas gracias @david

Comment: Nótese que esto es una simple copia de [esta respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973358/1983854). Por lo menos copia el markdown para que se vea bien :P

Answer (score -2):

A mi me va muy bien con esta configuración:

```
{
  "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php",
  "phpformatter.composer": true,
  "php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "${extensionPath}/php-cs-fixer.phar",
  "php-cs-fixer.lastDownload": 1535374941673,
  "editor.fontFamily": "SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "php-cs-fixer.formatHtml": true
}
```

Comment: Hola Anderson, aunque esta respuesta puede servir de ayuda para resolver el problema de la pregunta, es importante que añadas una descripción de la configuración que compartes y una explicación de por qué o cómo resolvería la duda expuesta. Lee [answer] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y ganar tu primera medalla).